# How to call Random Class name from the Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to call a class name listed from the array. I have the code below but it seems it doesnt work. Not sure why.

```
<div class="CALL RANDOM CLASSNAME FROM THE ARRAY USING PHP"></DIV>
```

Below is the PHP Code.

```
<?php
    $rdiv = array("onediv", "twodiv", "threediv", "fourdiv", "fivediv");
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
?>
<div class="<?php echo $rdiv[$rand_keys[0]]; ?>">

</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `It doesn't work` is not enough. Do you have an error or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed your apostrophes.

```
<div class="<?php $rdiv = array('onediv', 'twodiv', 'threediv', 'fourdiv', 'fivediv'); $rand_keys = array_rand($rdiv, 1); echo $rdiv[$rand_keys[0]];?>">

</div>
```

And you should extract some code there

```
<?php 
   $rdiv = array('onediv', 'twodiv', 'threediv', 'fourdiv', 'fivediv');
   $rand_keys = array_rand($rdiv, 1); 
?>
<div class="<?php echo $rdiv[$rand_keys[0]]; ?>">

</div>
```

Comment: `You mixed your apostrophes.` That should't be an issue, because PHP doesn't care about the surrounding HTML and the code doesn't print and quote characters.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do it if you don't need the value in a variable anywhere:

```
<div class='<?= array_rand(array_flip(['onediv', 'twodiv', 'threediv', 'fourdiv', 'fivediv'])) ?>'>
```

Normally, `array_rand()` returns a random key, but to avoid the juggling of storing that in a variable and then requesting that value from the array, we can just flip the provided set so that the strings are keys and randomly return one. This is only an option when values are unique.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong input for `array_rand();`. The array which you intended to use was `$rdiv`.

`$rand_keys` will also be an integer here (not an array), so you need to alter your `echo` statement. The docs say:

> When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. ([Source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php))

Putting it all together:

```
$rdiv = array("onediv", "twodiv", "threediv", "fourdiv", "fivediv"); 
$rand_keys = array_rand($rdiv, 1); 

echo $rdiv[$rand_keys];
```